# Elasticsearch - Add key value pair entries as values to one of the fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following schema for an index called '

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "my_type": {
            "properties": {
                "name": { 
                    "type" : "text", 
                    "fields": { 
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword", 
                            "ignore_above": 256 
                        } 
                    }
                },
                "tags": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "dynamic": "true"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The tags field accepts key value pairs as value. Something of the following format:

```
{
    "name": "proj2",
    "tags": {
        "Key-1": "Val-1",
        "Key-2": "Val-2"
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is the number of fields for the index increases whenever there are unique keys (as they are added as fields to the index). The default limit for number of fields for an index is 1000, which is hit with the increasing number of unique keys.

Increasing the default limit setting will have performance issues is what this document states - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#mapping-limit-settings

Another way is to have a static mapping as follows:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "my_type": {
            "properties": {
                "name": { 
                    "type" : "text", 
                    "fields": { 
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword", 
                            "ignore_above": 256 
                        } 
                    }
                },
                "tags": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "dynamic": "false"
                    "properties": {
                        "key": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "value": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        },     
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the above will separate the keys and values. This is not what I want.

Is there a way where we can store the values as key value pairs with dynamic set to false?

Answer (score 0):

The following schema worked for me:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "my_type": {
            "properties": {
                "name": { 
                    "type" : "text", 
                    "fields": { 
                        "keyword": {
                            "type": "keyword", 
                            "ignore_above": 256 
                        } 
                    }
                },
                "tags": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "dynamic": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This ensure that the data is stored in source, but not indexed, hence not adding to the number of fields.

Comment: Is there any way to store data as key value pairs and also search? For example: get all documents which have key as key-1 and value as value-1.